# Android Studio 0.4.2 Generate Client Libraries failing because of wrong folder name in path

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

In 0.4.0 and 0.4.2 (1/9/14 build) Generate Client Libraries gives an alert that the endpoints tree cannot be found.  Although the libraries are in fact generated they don't get copied into app-endpoints as they should.

This is a bug and can be tracked at :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=4&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=64537

What is the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

To work around the failure of the automatic copy look for the generated code in app-AppEngine/google_generated  like so...

After Generate Client Libraries, the code in 
app-AppEngine/google_generated/endpoint/lib-expanded-source//endpoint/

{there are three .java files; endpoint.java, endpointRequest.java, and endpointRequestInitializer.java,
additionally there is a "model" folder with .java and CollectionResponse.java
}

are in fact the client libraries. copy them into 
app-endpoints/src/endpoint-src/java/

good to go.